# Puppet reports returning only hash values for out-of-sync files

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

When I run `puppet agent -t` in agent nodes, I get difference values as

```
--- filepath      2019-11-18 05:00:22.136468706 +0000
+++ /tmp/puppet-file20191129-10421-1wpk2cq      2019-11-29 09:57:33.758735026 +0000
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
-# server_value 
+template value
```

in console/logs, but if the same thing is run through puppet run interval I get only

```
current_value '{md5}7653156283622979b3973a6546de2019', should be '{md5}f44bf134e4b07f94120483c40ffe5763'  hash value.
```

I need to know what are the specific values that are changed during puppet run instead of this hash value.

Comment: Are you talking about the console / log output produced by the agent?  "Reports" are a different thing in Puppet.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes Exactly,I need a log with changed values same as we get during puppet task run or either puppet agent -t

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is controlled by the Puppet configuration option [`show_diff`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.10/configuration.html#showdiff) in the main configuration file.  It defaults to `false`, but it is among several settings tweaked by the `-t` command-line option.  To get diffs by default, you would want to set

```
show_diff = true
```

in the `[agent]` section of each agent node's [puppet.conf](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/config_file_main.html) file.  After modifying the file, you will need to restart the puppet service for the new setting to take effect.